# How to stop Powershell insisting on one dash in parameters?

Tags: powershell

It seems that somebody has subtly changed the way that parameter switches are parsed on powershell.  On some machines "split-path c:\x\y --parent" works.  On some it fails.  Can anyone tell me a) what causes the difference and b) how can I stop it?

Comment: A year later, I still don't know why early versions of powershell consumed double dashes.  Newer machines don't and indeed, we converted all of our scripts across.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch parameters should work in the same way in both V1 and V2 (that means `-parent` is the right syntax).

In your case `--parent` should be bound to an parameter as a string. It should not be interpreted as a switch. You can test the binding via `Trace-Command`

```
Trace-Command parameterbinding -Expression { split-path c:\x\y --parent} -PSHost
```

*Further info:*

Considering `--`: every string behind `--` is interpreted as argument, no matter if it looks like a switch.

```
[14]: function test { 
    param([switch]$sw, [string]$str) 
    write-host switch is $sw
    write-host str is $str 
}
[15]: test 1
switch is False
str is 1
[16]: test -sw
switch is True
str is
[17]: test -- -sw
switch is False
str is -sw
```

Comment: Completely agree that single dash is correct.  The problem is, we've got 100-odd scripts that use double dash and it works on most machines in the office.