# PowerShell command line parameters and '--'

Tags: powershell, command-line, powershell-2.0

For whatever reason, when I try to call a C# program I'm writing, and I try to pass two arguments with '--' in the command line, PowerShell doesn't call the program with my command line.

For instance, I'm providing the command line:

```
.\abc.exe foo.txt -- bar --
```

When I call this, the C# program's main only gets the command line arguments:

```
foo.txt bar --
```

instead of

```
foo.txt -- bar --
```

as would be expected.

Why would this be happening?

BTW, if I call it as:

```
.\abc.exe foo.txt '--' bar '--'
```

it works as expected.

Also, calling it as:

```
& .\abc.exe foo.txt -- bar --
```

Doesn't seem to help.

My reason for thinking this is a PowerShell weirdness is that if I run the same command line from CMD.EXE, everything works as expected.

Comment: a further note.  apparently the two '--' isn't the whole problem.  It seems that powershell dropbx the first '--' even if the second one isn't there.  Seems like -- must have special meaning for powershell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A double hyphen instructs PowerShell to treat everything coming after as literal arguments rather than options, so that you can pass for instance a literal `-foo` to your script/application/cmdlet.

Example:

```
PS C:\> echo "-bar" | select-string -bar
Select-String : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'bar'.
At line:1 char:28
+ "-bar" | select-string -bar <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

vs.

```
PS C:\> echo "-bar" | select-string -- -bar

-bar
```

To avoid this behavior you must either quote (`"--"`, `'--'`) or escape (`` `-- ``) the double hyphen.

Comment: Can you give a reference to doc somewhere that describes the purpose of '--' and how it instructs PS to do this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12198146/1630171) from @ravikanth to a similar question cites "Windows PowerShell in Action", but other than that I don't have a source. It's consistent with other shells, though (`bash` for instance).

Comment: Here's a source for running executables in PowerShell that's well worth looking at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Comment: @JamieSee I don't see the double-dash discussed in that article, only the "stop parsing" parameter (`--%`) that was introduced with PowerShell v3.

Comment: I anyone is looking for the official docs about this `--` feature, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3#the-end-of-parameters-token) it is.

Answer (score 9):

With [PowerShell 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx) you can use `--%` to stop the normal parsing PowerShell does.

```
.\abc.exe --% foo.txt -- bar --
```