# Setting git hist to pretty print log via an alias on Windows

Tags: windows, git, powershell

Doing this:

```sh
git config --global alias.hist 'log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short'
```

[as mentioned](http://githowto.com/aliases) on a Windows machine just gives me
this error:

```
usage: git config [options]
```

when I try running `git hist`. Any suggestions why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

I could not pick up the command to add `hist` alias to `git`. But I am directly insert it into `.gitconfig` file that usually can be located at `"C:\Users\<login name>\"` or `"C:\Documents and Settings\<login name>\"`.

Look at fragment of my `.gitconfig` file, and note the changes to be made to the `hist` alias so that it worked fine under Windows.

```
[alias]
    co = checkout
    ci = commit
    st = status
    br = branch
    hist = !git --no-pager log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short
    type = cat-file -t
    dump = cat-file -p
```

Comment: i forgot this \ after "format" ,t his was the error

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is doing funny stuff with the last argument. You can stop this like
so

```sh
git config --global alias.hist --% 'blah blah blah'
#                              ^
#                             / 
#                  notice ----
```

[Powershell command line parameters and '--'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15780174/#16376385)

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes:

```
git config --global alias.hist "log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short"
```