# gcloud compute ssh port forwarding in powershell

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform

I would like to use `gcloud compute ssh` with portforwarding options in windows. When I executed following command in "Google Cloud SDK Shell" shortcut on desktop, it worked.

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud CLI! Run "gcloud -h" to get the list of available commands.
---

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute ssh instance-name --tunnel-through-iap -- -L xxxx:localhost:vvvv
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>
```

But when I executed same command in powershell, it failed.

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx> gcloud compute ssh instance-name --tunnel-through-iap -- -L  xxxx:localhost:vvvv
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) unrecognized arguments:
  -L
  xxxx:localhost:vvvv
  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
```

How can I pass SSH args to gcloud command in powershell?  I could not use past command history in "Google Cloud SDK Shell" shortcut, so I would like to use powershell (in which I can use past command history). Thanks.

Comment: You should add gcloud cli to your PATH env variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037279/gcloud-command-not-found-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk

Comment: Thanks, when I executed commands without SSH args(`-- -L xxxx:localhost:vvvv`), it works.

Answer (score 2):

I should quote 2 dashes as `'--'` when I execute commands in powershell. Following command works in powershell according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780174/powershell-command-line-parameters-and#:%7E:text=A%20double%20hyphen%20instructs%20PowerShell,your%20script%2Fapplication%2Fcmdlet.).

```
gcloud compute ssh instance-name --tunnel-through-iap '--' -L  xxxx:localhost:vvvv
```